# Adding a pattern to compilation-error-regexp-alist

Tags: compilation, compilation-mode, doom

I'm using the latest [Doom Emacs](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs) on Emacs 27 with this config: https://github.com/gregghz/doom-config/tree/d3af4724cb4a5dd379645580698f7d24a5c3922a.

I have [this code](https://github.com/gregghz/doom-config/blob/d3af4724cb4a5dd379645580698f7d24a5c3922a/bloop/bloop.el#L80) to run a bloop command (like `bloop compile`) and have the results pop up in a `compilation-mode` buffer. My understanding was that adding entries to `compilation-error-regexp-alist` would allow `compilation-mode` to detect and linkify all errors in the output (and jump to the first one).

I have this in my [config.el](https://github.com/gregghz/doom-config/blob/d3af4724cb4a5dd379645580698f7d24a5c3922a/config.el#L58):

```
(after! compile
  (add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist '(bloop "^\\[E\\] \\([A-Za-z0-9\\._/-]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):.*$" 1 2 3))
  (add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist 'bloop))
```

Here is some example error output from the buffer:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/workspace/scratch/scala/" -*-
Compilation started at Tue Jul 14 07:32:08

bloop compile --reporter scalac scala
Compiling scala (1 Scala source)
[E] /Users/gher33/workspace/scratch/scala/src/main/scala/Main.scala:4:34: not found: type Units
[E]   def main(args: Array[String]): Units = {
[E]                                  ^
[E] /Users/gher33/workspace/scratch/scala/src/main/scala/Main.scala:5:17: not found: type Thing
[E]     val x = new Thing
[E]                 ^
[E] /Users/gher33/workspace/scratch/scala/src/main/scala/Main.scala:8:19: value f is not a member of Int
[E]   lazy val x = 10 f
[E]                   ^
[E] three errors found
Compiled scala (991ms)
[E] Failed to compile 'scala'

Compilation exited abnormally with code 8 at Tue Jul 14 07:32:10
```

Testing the regex with `regexp-builder` matches each of the three errors. However in the `compilation-mode` buffer none of the errors are detected or linkified.

What am I missing?

**=EDIT=**

Running `describe-mode` produces this output:

```
Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Better-Jumper Better-Jumper-Local Clipetty
Column-Number Company Company-Prescient Dap Dap-Auto-Configure Dap-Tooltip
Dap-Ui Dap-Ui-Controls Dap-Ui-Many-Windows Doom-Modeline Electric-Indent Evil
Evil-Escape Evil-Goggles Evil-Local Evil-Snipe Evil-Snipe-Local
Evil-Snipe-Override Evil-Snipe-Override-Local Evil-Surround File-Name-Shadow
Flyspell-Lazy Font-Lock Gcmh General-Override Global-Clipetty Global-Company
Global-Eldoc Global-Evil-Surround Global-Flycheck Global-Font-Lock
Global-Git-Commit Global-Magit-File Global-So-Long Global-Undo-Tree Ivy
Ivy-Posframe Ivy-Prescient Ivy-Rich Line-Number Mouse-Wheel Ns-Auto-Titlebar
Override-Global Persp Prescient-Persist Projectile Recentf Save-Place Savehist
Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Size-Indication Smartparens-Global Solaire-Global
Transient-Mark Treemacs-Filewatch Treemacs-Follow Treemacs-Fringe-Indicator
Treemacs-Git Undo-Tree Which-Key Window-Divider Winner Ws-Butler
Ws-Butler-Global Xterm-Mouse

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

Compilation mode defined in ‘compile.el’:
Major mode for compilation log buffers.
To visit the source for a line-numbered error,
move point to the error message line and type RET.
To kill the compilation, type C-c C-k.
```

If I run `compilation-mode` in that buffer, linkification happens and the links work. The output of `describe-mode` doesn't change.

The buffer is created/summoned with this code:

```
(defun bloop-exec (comint root command &rest args)
  (unless command (error "Missing argument `command'."))

  (let* ((buffer-name (bloop-buffer-name root command))
         (raw-command (cons bloop-program-name (cons command args)))
         (full-command (string-join (mapcar 'shell-quote-argument raw-command) " "))
         (inhibit-read-only 1))

    (when (not (executable-find bloop-program-name))
      (error (concat "`%s' not found. Is bloop installed and on PATH? "
                     "See `bloop-program-name' variable.")
             bloop-program-name))

    (if comint
        (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create buffer-name)
          (pop-to-buffer-same-window (current-buffer))
          ;; (read-only-mode)
          (buffer-disable-undo)
          (if (comint-check-proc (current-buffer))
              (error "A bloop command is still running!")
            ;; TODO: Maybe save buffers?
            (cd root)
            (erase-buffer)
            (insert (concat root "$ " full-command))
            (newline 2)
            (comint-mode)
            ;; (compilation-shell-minor-mode)
            (comint-exec (current-buffer) buffer-name bloop-program-name nil (cons command args))
            (current-buffer)))
      (let ((compilation-buffer-name-function (lambda (mode) buffer-name)))
        (cd root)
        (compile full-command)))))
```

Comment: Not sure that it fixes the problem but the `-` after the `9` in the filename character class is probably wrong: if you are looking to match a literal `-`, you have to put it either at the beginning or at the end of the character class.

Comment: thanks, I updated it, but I do still have the same issue.

Comment: Is the `compilation-mode` buffer in `compilation-mode`? The reason that I ask is that if I create a file with the contents above, close and reopen the file (to get the file local variable to take effect and put the buffer in `compilation-mode`), I get the errors recognized and linkified *without adding anything to the regexp alist* (of course, the links are bad on my system but still...)

Comment: okay that's strange. In the modeline I see "Compilation", click that shows a
list of compilation-mode actions. `describe-mode` also shows "Compilation mode
defined in 'compile.el'". HOWEVER, if i run `compilation-mode` while in the
buffer, it does actually linkify the errors. I've updated the question with additional info about this.

Comment: Thanks to you @NickD I figured it out. `bloop-exec` was always called with `comint` set to nil so it would always hit the else branch. Change `(compile full-command)` to `(compile full-command t)` fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

Changing `(compile full-command)` to `(compile full-command t)` in `bloop-exec` fixes the issue.

Comment: Where did the `bloop-exec` code come from? Is it part of a public package?

Comment: @NickD it was linked originally as part of my config. I wrote it.